# Publish existing API in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to publish an API using the API Manager. I am getting the following error: "API validation failed." My API also has a password, but I can not find out how to add this to the API Manager.[image: Open API Validation Failed]

Comment: If you are getting any error message in the carbon logs, can you please share that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an API using an OpenAPI definition. The OpenAPI definition is validated when you provide the URL here. Please make sure that you have a valid OpenAPI definition in that URL.

If you are a trying to create a simple API without an OpenAPI definition, please use the option **Start from Scratch** and provide your backend URL there.

Answer (score 1):

If the OpenAPI definition is password protected, then API Manager is not able to retrieve the OpenAPI definition. You can download the OpenAPI definition into the file system. Then use the OpenAPI file option to create an API.

Refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/create-a-rest-api-from-an-openapi-definition/#create-an-api-using-the-basic-flow